# Contact Tabs links gone away When clicking on Pager Next/Prev/Page Change under My Custom Tab for Contact

Tags: contacts

Here is my code of .tpl file:

```
<div class="view-content">
<h3>...</h3>
{include file="CRM/common/pager.tpl" location="top"}
{strip}
    <table class="display">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        {foreach from=$rows item=row}
            ...
        {/foreach}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{/strip}
{include file="CRM/common/pager.tpl" location="bottom"}
</div>
{include file="CRM/common/jsortable.tpl"}
```

and Code for setting up Pager:

```
/**
 * Setting up $_pager for pagination support
 * Used CRM_Utils_Pager & CRM/common/pager.tpl to handle pagination
 */
public function pager() {
    // Setting up parameters for Pager that we are gonna create
    $params['status'] = ts('Some Entity %%StatusMessage%%');
    $params['csvString'] = NULL;
    $params['buttonTop'] = 'PagerTopButton';
    $params['buttonBottom'] = 'PagerBottomButton';
    $params['rowCount'] = $this->get(CRM_Utils_Pager::PAGE_ROWCOUNT);
    if (!$params['rowCount']) {
        $params['rowCount'] = CRM_Utils_Pager::ROWCOUNT;
    }

    // Getting all Some Entity by Contact ID. if $_contactId is null then it return value for all Contact.
    $params['total'] = civicrm_api3( 'Entity', 'getcount', array( 'contact_id' => $this->_contactId ) );;

    // Setup Pager object and assign into template so it can be used by CRM/common/pager.tpl
    $this->_pager = new CRM_Utils_Pager($params);
    $this->assign_by_ref('pager', $this->_pager);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Problem, Problem was inside pager.tpl

pager.tpl generate some js to handle ajax page loading When pager.tpl location variable != top

That's js look like this without compiled(in pager.tpl):

```
{if $location neq 'top'}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    {literal}
    CRM.$(function($) {
      {/literal}
      var
        $form = $({if empty($form.formClass)}'#crm-main-content-wrapper'{else}'form.{$form.formClass}'{/if}),
        numPages = {$pager->_response.numPages},
        currentPage = {$pager->_response.currentPage},
        perPageCount = {$pager->_perPage},
        currentLocation = {$pager->_response.currentLocation|json_encode},
        spinning = null,
        refreshing = false;
      {literal}
      function refresh(url) {
        if (!refreshing) {
          refreshing = true;
          var options = url ? {url: url} : {};
          $form.off('.crm-pager').closest('.crm-ajax-container, #crm-main-content-wrapper').crmSnippet(options).crmSnippet('refresh');
        }
      }

      ...

      $form
        .on('click.crm-pager', 'a.ui-spinner-button', function(e) {
          var $el = $(this);
          // Update after a short delay to allow multiple clicks
          spinning !== null && window.clearTimeout(spinning);
          spinning = window.setTimeout(function() {
            if ($el.is('.crm-pager a')) {
              page($el.siblings('input[name^=crmPID]').spinner('value'));
            } else {
              changeCount($el.siblings('input.crm-rows-per-page-select').spinner('value'));
            }
          }, 200);
        })
        // Handle sorting, paging and alpha filtering links
        .on('click.crm-pager', 'a.crm-pager-link, #alpha-filter a, th a.sorting, th a.sorting_desc, th a.sorting_asc', function(e) {
          refresh($(this).attr('href'));
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    {/literal}
  </script>
```

`#crm-main-content-wrapper` is the main container of All tabs link and tab content. that's why it's html/content replaced by ajax response html.

## **To fix this what I have done:**

Here is my .tpl file code(after fixed):

```
<form class="Your_Unique_Class_Name">
<div class="view-content">
  <h3>...</h3>
  {include file="CRM/common/pager.tpl" location="top"}
  {strip}
   <table class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    {foreach from=$rows item=row}
        ...
    {/foreach}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {/strip}
    {include file="CRM/common/pager.tpl" location="bottom"}
</div>
{include file="CRM/common/jsortable.tpl"}
</form>
```

and Code for setting up Pager:

```
/**
 * Setting up $_pager for pagination support
 * Used CRM_Utils_Pager & CRM/common/pager.tpl to handle pagination
 */
public function pager() {


    $this->assign( 'form', array( 'formClass' => 'Your_Unique_Class_Name' ) );


    // Setting up parameters for Pager that we are gonna create
    $params['status'] = ts('Some Entity %%StatusMessage%%');
    $params['csvString'] = NULL;
    $params['buttonTop'] = 'PagerTopButton';
    $params['buttonBottom'] = 'PagerBottomButton';
    $params['rowCount'] = $this->get(CRM_Utils_Pager::PAGE_ROWCOUNT);
    if (!$params['rowCount']) {
        $params['rowCount'] = CRM_Utils_Pager::ROWCOUNT;
    }

    // Getting all Some Entity by Contact ID. if $_contactId is null then it return value for all Contact.
    $params['total'] = civicrm_api3( 'Entity', 'getcount', array( 'contact_id' => $this->_contactId ) );;

    // Setup Pager object and assign into template so it can be used by CRM/common/pager.tpl
    $this->_pager = new CRM_Utils_Pager($params);
    $this->assign_by_ref('pager', $this->_pager);
}
```

It's taken me long hours to find out this problem solution;

I think it will help you so that's why sharing with you!

Thanks